# Why used the word "would" in the sentence?

Tags: modal-verbs

In lyric Papa there is a sentence. "Everyday my papa would work to try to make ends meet to see that we would eat keep those shoes upon my feet". Why used "Would" in the phrase "Everyday my papa would work" I know "would" to talk about the past or to talk about hypotheses.I can use " Everyday my papa works to try to make ends meet...?" Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you quote and the version you'd prefer have different meanings.

> "Everyday my papa would work to try to make ends meet..."

means that this happened in the past and probably isn't happening anymore. Their papa may no longer work -- he could be dead. The use of **would** in this sentence is describing a **past habitual** occurrence.

Your change

> "Everyday my papa works to try to make ends meet..."

means that this is the ***present* habitual**, not the past. This is perfectly fine if it's still true that their father works to try to make ends meet *now*, but because they used "would" in the original, that probably *isn't* true.